# Moving badges to Meta

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

I noticed my gold answer (along with the question) was moved to the Meta site. Shouldn't my points and badge be moved here as well?

Answer (score 2):

Your badge wasn't moved, it just clocked in Meta for when the question itself was moved and [your answer was counted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions/7054#7054).

Your points wouldn't be moved because they don't mean the same thing out there in the wild SO than in Meta.

Comment: so, it is kinda like I got some items/reward/xp from a quest in an MMORPG that is only seasonally available and not permanent? ;-)

Comment: You might lose beavers, but you don't lose badges.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't seem like your badge was *moved*, more like you got another one. your badge on SO still exists.

Comment: My question is, shouldn't my badge be moved to Meta? it seems "empty" to have a gold badge in SO since the question/answer is gone.

Comment: of course, it should. what are other options?

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* the points will be, but the badge will (hence my "great answer" badge here, for the Jon Skeet Facts question).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if when a rep recalc is called you will get the rep from a migrated question, or if it intentionally skips over migrated questions (which doesn't make the most sense).

Comment: I've recalced my rep a couple times, and I still haven't the faintest idea how the dang thing behaves.